# No Data Context Found For Binding in MAUI

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui, mobile-development

I have a page to manage the data packets and in this page i have created a collection view part to view all the data s. But when i try to bind the viewer data, program says that there is no data context.

Here`s the code of the page in xaml:
`<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding PacketModels}">`

And here is the code that i`m trying to bind it in my view model in C#:

```
           public sealed class ManageDataPacketsViewModel 
{

    public ObservableCollection<PacketModel> PacketModels
    {
        get { return MainDb.Instance.PacketCache; }
    }

    //public ObservableCollection<PacketModel> PacketModels => MainDb.Instance.PacketCache;

    public ManageDataPacketsViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information - we don't know whether you've successfully bound the context that *contains* `PacketModels`, for example. Are you able to use *other* properties in the same class? (As an aside, your property would be more concisely expressed as `public ObservableCollection<PacketModel> PacketModels => MainDb.Instance.PacketCache;`)

Comment: Please provide your XAML too.

Comment: Is it similar to this thread : [Picker ItemDisplayBinding "No DataContext found for Binding", yet it still works properly](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4818) ? You could show us how you bind your page to viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to refresh the packages every time we got a new one. So the code should be like this.

```
 public ManageDataPacketsViewModel()
    {
        MainDb.Instance.RefreshDataPacketCache();
    }
```